# Blurry Import Images

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I am creating logos and simple images in Illustrator and when I import the AI file OR the png into the InDesign document they are blurry. I have already selected the High-Performance view and it changes the other images but not the imported ones.

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - *please* take a look around through [tour] and hopefully get a sense of who we are and what we're about as a community. Please also look over [ask] and [answer] questions whilst you're at it, to learn how best to formulate queries and what to expect from replies and answers. I'm not aware of "importing" Illustrator files or .pngs as a workflow with InDesign, but rather of "placing" them, which retains links to those outside resources unless you subsequently manually embed them; AFAIK, "import" specifically applies only to XML files; how are you "importing" these?

Answer (score 1):

changing the display quality can be done globally to the file (InDesign > Preferences > Display Performance), or to the individual elements (View > Display Performance). Check both. If you have "preserve object level display settings" checked in the Preferences, then you need to uncheck it, or go to the individual objects and change them there.

Answer (score 0):

May still be a preview issue and this has been reported before. The ultimate test is to export a PDF and see what that looks like. If it's indeed a preview issue, the PDF should look sharp and correct.